Examples of cyclic A-infinity algebra
I am wondering about (references to) examples of cyclic A-infinity algebras- especially including explicit descriptions of the structure maps and pairing.
Thanks a lot!

There are cyclic $A_\infty$ algebras arising from quivers with potentials, see for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0452. The structure maps in this case are determined explicitly by the potential.

Solomon and Tukachinsky provided an accessible and concrete construction of cyclic unital curved $A_{\infty}$ algebras associated with Lagrangian submanifolds in their paper:

Solomon, Jake P.; Tukachinsky, Sara B., Differential forms, Fukaya (A_\infty) algebras, and Gromov-Witten axioms, J. Symplectic Geom. 20, No. 4, 927-994 (2022). ZBL1516.53077.

They use differential forms to construct these algebras, which means the structure maps can, in principle, be computed by integrating differential forms over the moduli spaces of (J)-holomorphic curves. By focusing on a specific class of Lagrangian submanifolds, they avoid the need for virtual fundamental class techniques, making their construction more explicit and approachable. They use these operators to define and compute open Gromov-Witten invariants and establish their properties in:

Solomon, Jake P.; Tukachinsky, Sara B., Relative quantum cohomology, ZBL07891444.

In this work, they compute explicit numerical invariants using the operators and pairings, making their construction highly concrete.
Their work builds on the foundational ideas of Fukaya-Oh-Ohta-Ono:

Fukaya, Kenji; Oh, Yong-Geun; Ohta, Hiroshi; Ono, Kaoru, Lagrangian intersection Floer theory. Anomaly and obstruction. II, AMS/IP Studies in Advanced Mathematics 46,2. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); Somerville, MA: International Press (ISBN 978-0-8218-4837-1/hbk). xii, 397-805. (2009). ZBL1181.53003.

and extends the work of Fukaya and Fukaya-Oh-Ohta-Ono, who revisited and expanded $A_{\infty}$ algebra theory using the language of differential forms:

Fukaya, Kenji, Cyclic symmetry and adic convergence in Lagrangian Floer theory, Kyoto J. Math. 50, No. 3, 521-590 (2010). ZBL1205.53090.
Fukaya, Kenji, Counting pseudo-holomorphic discs in Calabi-Yau 3-holds, Tohoku Math. J. (2) 63, No. 4, Centen. Iss., 697-727 (2011). ZBL1244.57046.
Fukaya, Kenji; Oh, Yong-Geun; Ohta, Hiroshi; Ono, Kaoru, Lagrangian Floer theory on compact toric manifolds. I., Duke Math. J. 151, No. 1, 23-175 (2010). ZBL1190.53078.
Fukaya, Kenji; Oh, Yong-Geun; Ohta, Hiroshi; Ono, Kaoru, Lagrangian Floer theory on compact toric manifolds. II: Bulk deformations, Sel. Math., New Ser. 17, No. 3, 609-711 (2011). ZBL1234.53023.
Fukaya, Kenji; Oh, Yong-Geun; Ohta, Hiroshi; Ono, Kaoru, Lagrangian Floer theory and mirror symmetry on compact toric manifolds, Astérisque 376. Paris: Société Mathématique de France (SMF) (ISBN 978-2-85629-825-1/pbk). vi, 340 p. (2016). ZBL1344.53001.

